# C - No output data

Tags: c

I have a problem with my source code. When I do this, I have no output data, why ? How I can resolve this please ? 
Thank's !

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ft_split_whitespaces(char *str);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ft_split_whitespaces("Hello\nThis is\ta\nWord");
    return (0);
}

void ft_split_whitespaces(char *str)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i);
    {
        if (str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\t' || str[i] == ' ')
        {
            printf("Ascii table (int): %d, Ascii table (char): %c\n", str[i], str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typographical error - semicolon at the end of `for` means empty statement - `for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i);`.

Fix: remove semicolon and never put one even instead of empty statement at the end of `for`/`while`/`if` - use `{ /* intentionally empty */}` instead

```
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) // no semicolon here ever.
{
    if (str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\t' || str[i] == ' ')
    {
        printf("Ascii table (int): %d, Ascii table (char): %c\n", str[i], str[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What Alexei said.

To avoid that, I like to use this sort of curly bracing:

```
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
    if (str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\t' || str[i] == ' '){
        printf("Ascii table (int): %d, Ascii table (char): %c\n", str[i], str[i]);
    }
}
```

This way the first thing you do after completing the conditions in a loop is put an open curly brace, instead of accidentally put a semicolon by reflex, and then jump down and put an open curly brace.

Comment: [Egyptian Brackets](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) (also know K&R brackets/style) is indeed another way to help yourself to avoid semicolon-only statements... As long as your coding style guide support that (C/JavaScript usually do). Additionally looking at compile time warning is another (and safer) way.

Comment: @Alexei: One does not preclude the other. ishyfishy's argument for K&R bracing style is actually quite compelling.